# Having problem with package manager Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I am trying to install any new package, I am getting this:

```
(Reading database ... 170573 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 10: /etc/default/grub: quiet splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I ran `Sudo apt-get upgrade` but I got the same error message.

Contents of grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= "quiet splash" nouveau.modeset=0 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Sounds like your `/etc/default/grub` is malformed.  You'll need to include its contents here for us to debug/diagnose it

Comment: @ThomasWard I added the contents of GRUB

Comment: Try to change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to read exactly (including whitespace) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"` and try again

Comment: @LienhartWoitok Thank You soo much!!!I was stuck due this. But one doubt, what is the issue of nvidia drivers with Ubuntu 18.04? Coz I made that change due to display driver issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= "quiet splash" nouveau.modeset=0` is your problem. When parsed as shell script (which it obviously is) it tries to run command `quiet splash` with argument `nouveau.modeset=0` and the environment variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` set to empty. This doesn't work.

Instead, it just should assign a value to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. To achieve this you need to make sure that after the `=` there is no whitespace and the complete value is contained in the quotes, like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
```